# Как сделать так чтобы метод запускался после отработки такого же метода(с другим значением переменной)

Tags: java, javafx

Есть метод

```
public int TIMER_funk(int seco) {
    this.sec = seco;

    timer_sec.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (sec > 0) {
                        sec--;
                        int minutes = sec / 60;
                        int seconds = sec % 60;

                        SECONDS.setTextFill(seconds < 4 ? Color.RED : Color.BLACK);
                        MINUTES.setText((minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + minutes);
                        SECONDS.setText((seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + seconds);
                    } else if (sec == 0) {
                        sec = 9;
                        int count = 1;
                        Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
                        alert.setTitle("You need a break");
                        alert.setHeaderText(null);
                        alert.setContentText("5 minutes!!!");
                        alert.showAndWait();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000, 1000);
    return 1;
}
```

В другом методе мне нужно чтобы этот запускался больше одного рвза

```
TIMER_funk(15);
TIMER_funk(22);
```

> ВОТ ТАК ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ, но скорость увеличивается.

```
ScheduledExecutorService execService =   Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

        execService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         TIMER_funk(15);

     }
     public void run2() { 
     }


     public void run3() {

         TIMER_funk(10);
     }
 }, 0, 16, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение на "вскидку".
Создайте наследника Runnable интерфейса, в котором объявите очередь LinkedBlockedQueue. В нее вы будете добавлять ту задачу, которую надо выполнить по таймеру с заданными параметрами. После получения задачи из очереди, запускаете ее через ScheduledExecutorService и делаете для ScheduledFuture метод get() дожидаясь пока она исполнится.

Таким образом - два раза добавите - два раза выполнится. Три - значит три. Причем последовательно.

Comment: У меня получилось, но скорость отчета увеличивается вдвое. Как от этого избавится??

Comment: Пояснительная пожалуйста подробнее.

Comment: После того как первый  TIMER_funk(15); отработал отчитывая в обратном направлении 15 сек и перерыв в 9 сек, подключается второй TIMER_funk(10); но с бешеной скоростью, где две секунды проходят за одну реальную. То есть sec-- налаживаются друг на друга.

Comment: Опять не то( Я ни как не могу понять условия задачи. Пожалуйста, сформулируйте ее более конкретно или академично, а я вам постараюсь дать решение.

Comment: TIMER_funk это метод в котором идет обратный отчет секунд sec--. После того как первый раз TIMER_funk(15); отработал(эта операция повторяется несколько раз ) включается еще один, но к sec-- добавляется еще sec--, значит скорость обратного отчета увеличивается в разы. Как это прекратить? Как сделать так чтобы при включении второго потока программа начиналась с чистого листа как при первом включении?? return; уже пробовал - не помогло

Comment: Теперь понял)) Смотрите, у вас в классе, где находится метод TIMER_funk объявлена переменная sec. Разумеется если вы два раза вызовете, ваш метод, то создастся два потока таймера, которые будут работать с одной ОБЩЕЙ переменной и будут ее уменьшать. Т.е. отработаю в два раза быстрей. А если три потока - то в три и т.д. Вам, нужно создать класс (не inner!!)  - наследник Runnable, в котором будет объявлена локальная переменная sec и тогда то, что будет в run() (т.е. Platform.runLater...) будет работать со своим экземпляром переменной и ни как не зависеть от других таймеров.